# More Succinct Elif Statement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a way to more efficiently code this? I tried np.where but there are so many conditions  and they're so complex I couldn't get it to work properly. I know there has to be a faster way then a massive elif statement, but It's the only way I could dump all of my conditions in there.  I'm running through about 1 million lines of excel so if there are other faster options I'd like to hear them!

Here is the code:

```
def pol_cost(x):
    if ( 9500000> x.CRV >= 50 ):
        if (x.MDI > MDI_var):
            if (x.CI < 40 ):
               return x.CRV
            elif (60 <= x.CI <80):
               return x.CRV*((100-x.CI)/(100-var_var))**x.Cost_Escalation_N
        else:
            return 0
    else: 
         return 0
    df1['Policy_Cost_Y1'] = df1.apply(pol_cost, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Is the indent off on your last line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@chepner's simplificiation of your conditional statements allows you to then vectorize the entire operation to

```
a = x.CI < 40
b = numpy.logical_and(
    60 <= x.CI,
    x.CI < 80,
)
c = numpy.logical_or(
    numpy.logical_and(
        9500000 > x.CRV,
        x.CRV >= 50
    ),
    x.MDI <= MDI_var,
)

tmp = numpy.zeros_like(x.CRV)
tmp[a] = x.CRV[a]
tmp[b] = x.CRV[b] * ((100-x.CI[b])/(100 - var_var))**x.Cost_Escalation_N[b],
tmp[c] = 0
df1['Policy_Cost_Y1'] = tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

A useful idiom is to handle the clause the returns immediately; then you don't *need* an `else` or `elif`.

```
def pos_cost(x):
    if not (9500000  > x.CRV >= 50):
        return 0

    if x.MDI <= MDI_var:
        return 0

    if x.CI < 40:
        return x.CRV
    elif 60 < x.CI < 80:
        return x.CRV * ((100-x.CI)/(100 - var_var))**x.Cost_Escalation_N

    df1['Policy_Cost_Y1'] = df1.apply(pol_cost, axis=1)
```

Note that since the first two `if` statements have the same result, you can combine them into a single statement:

```
if not (9500000 > x.CRV >= 50) or (x.MDI <= MDI_var):
    return 0
```

or after a little manipulation:

```
if 9500000 <= x.CRV or x.CRV < 50 or x.MDI <= MDI_var:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two first conditions with `and` and test the inverse of that. Then go with `elif` statements.

```
if not (9500000 > x.CRV >= 50 and x.MDI > MDI_var):
    return 0

elif x.CI < 40 :
    return x.CRV

elif 60 <= x.CI <80:
    return x.CRV*((100-x.CI)/(100-var_var))**x.Cost_Escalation_N

else:
    df1['Policy_Cost_Y1'] = df1.apply(pol_cost, axis = 1)
```

Comment: You are missing the unconditional statement at the end; not every path through the conditional ends at a `return` statement.

Comment: That's still not right.  The original code returns `None`, not `0`, when `x.CI >= 80`, and it updates the object `df1`.